# how to create 2 virtual machines in two different containers in the same storage account in windows azure?

Tags: azure

As we know that when we create any virtual machine in any storage account, the virtual machine is created in the same container(vhd). Can it be possible to create two virtual machines in the two different containers in the same storage account?

Comment: How are you creating the VM? Are you using Portal or PowerShell?

Comment: i am using using portal to create the vm.

Answer (score 0):

The location (storage container) and vhd name for a vhd is arbitrary. The portal doesn't give you any chance to change the container name or the vhd name.

But when dealing with Azure Resource Manager, where you're constructing your own creation configuration, you're free to specify any container name (and any vhd name, for that matter).